# Python: run appium server from command line failed due to path issue

Tags: python, command-line, appium

So i try to start `appium` server using this `command`:

```
import os
os.system("start /B start cmd.exe @cmd /k appium")
```

When i start `cmd` window ant type `appium` this start my server but with the above `command` i received this `error`:

> 'appium' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

And at the end i can see that the current `path` is the `path` where i run my `python` code so i suspect that this is the problem and i need to fix this `path`.

Any suggestions ?